# Add CSS to Joomla 3 template Admin Area

Tags: css, templates, joomla, admin

Is their any way to add a costume css to a joomla template admin area with a css file included in template package ?

Many thanks.

Comment: yes, there is. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Install below plug-in. It is used to remove joomla branding using css.

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/administration/admin-styling/23172

Go to administrator -> extensions-> plugin manager and enable it. Then edit it, remove default CSS and add your own CSS.